# How to install spotify on IOS

Tags: ios, spotify

Is there anyway to install spotify on IOS device, i have tried some like TweakBox but when i try to open the app it says the developer is not a trusted one so until he get the trust the app won't work!

Comment: you just need to trust app from general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error **developer is not a trusted**. Try this.
Got to **Settings-->General-->Device Management**
Inside Device Management you'll see the Enterprise app profile , you can select it and trust it.
It works fine for Jailbreak ipa files. Try and let me know.